# Place SVG in-line with html text headers

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll

I'd like to put an SVG hyperlink to the left of these two page links:

The site uses Jekyll and is built off [Poole](https://github.com/poole/poole). The site is nearly identical right now so any additional CSS details can be seen [in Poole's repo](https://github.com/poole/poole/tree/master/_sass)

I'm struggling with how to place an image or svg in the masthead class below. I'd like the logo to be inline with page navigation. The img tag below currently displays nothing.

```css
.masthead {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
}
.masthead-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: $gray-4;
}
.masthead-title a {
  color: inherit;
  }
.masthead-title small {
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: 400;
    opacity: .5;
  }
```

```html
<header class="masthead">
  <h3 class="masthead-title">

    <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/" title="Home">{{ <img src="/assets/logo_small.svg" height="25" width="100"/> }}</a> <!--site.title-->

    {% for page in site.pages_list %}
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<small><a href="{{ page[1]  }}">{{ page[0] }}</a></small>
    {% endfor %}

  </h3>
</header>
```

Comment: If you open developer tools in your browser is it showing that it can file the svg file?

Comment: Tangent: it's generally considered better practice to add something like `.masthead-title small {display: inline-block; padding-left: 20px;}` to your CSS, rather than using a bunch of non-breaking spaces -- it will make your markup easier to maintain, and adjusting the layout will be easier

Comment: Also, check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for notes on how to create a minimal, verifiable example, and consider editing the code you provided. Since SO can't run Liquid, `{{ }}` and `{% %}` functions could be replaced by dummy content. And you can leave out any CSS that isn't strictly related to the question -- in this case, probably leave out all the CSS unless in your tests you found that something in there is the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, it looks like the trouble is you put the image in a Liquid variable. It should be `<img ...>`, not `{{ <img ... > }}`

Here's a minimal snippet that removes everything not related to your question, showing the `<img>` inline with your links.

```css
.masthead img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header class="masthead">
  <h3>

    <a href="">
      <img src="/assets/logo_small.svg" />
    </a>

    <small>
      <a href="">link 1</a>
    </small>
    
    <small>
      <a href="">link 2</a>
    </small>

  </h3>
</header>
```

Comment: How do I then move that in line with the other page links?

Comment: I've added a minimal snippet, where you can see that the image is in line with the other links. If taking the `<img>` out of the `{{ }}` doesn't fix it for you, there is some other conflicting css